# Space Between in Nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

so I'm making a navbar and I used a space-between for my justify-content. But they seem to be too spread out. Is there a way to make it not so spread out? Or even pushing it away from the end of the page. Here's my code for it:

```
#navbar {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: #B8860B;
    background-color: #B8860B;
}
```

Comment: Hi. can you please post your HTML as well?

Comment: please show your html code also

Comment: You could also try space-around and space-evenly for justify-content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there definitely is a way. Try setting a padding on both the left and right hand side of the navbar to push the elements inward.

```
#navbar {
   ...
   padding: 0 25px;
   ...
}
```

Feel free to adjust the horizontal padding to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

add some padding to left and right of your navbar and it will fix it

```
#navbar {
font-size: 20px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
border: 5px solid;
border-color: #B8860B;
background-color: #B8860B;
padding: 0 45%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help